# Is there a verb (or group of verbs) to describe someone saying "hmm"?

Tags: single-word-requests, speech

I'm looking for a verb to replace someone uttering "hmm" or "mmh" or any of its variations.

I found this related question ([The origin of 'hmm'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429332/the-origin-of-hmm/429352#429352)) that hints that "hum" might be a good choice, but I'm wondering if there are others, possibly better ones.

It gets a bit more complicated given the many meanings of "hmm". Depending on context and tone, it can mean "I agree" or "I disagree", "I hear you" (with or without agreement) or "I'm not really listening". And when used in a question, it can also mean "Can you repeat that?"

So far I've got

> He hummed in agreement.
>
> He grunted noncommittally.

Can I use either of those to express the negative version?

> He hummed/grunted in disagreement.

And what about the question form?

> "Hmm?"

Comment: You also lacked to mention that "hmm" can be used in thought. There are many different meanings of this word, so maybe a different word should be used for different context.